# Automatically saving a file with QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I have to automate a test using QTest, Qt, C++:
I write text in a tab (part of tabwidget) and then try to close it, afterwards a QFileDialog appears ( because I made changes to the plaintext in the tab), I try to "catch" the QFileDialog like this:

```
    QWidgetList topWidgets = QApplication::topLevelWidgets();
    foreach (QWidget *w, topWidgets) {
        if (QFileDialog *fd = qobject_cast<QFileDialog *>(w)) {
            fd->setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
            fd->selectFile("/tmp/test.txt");

        }
    }
```

After getting the QFileDialog object I want my changes from the tab to be saved in the file "test.txt" which I created before in the tmp directory. When I execute this nothing happens, the QFileDialog pops up, but test.txt is not selected and not saved, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the fileDialog to automatically select the text file (just supply a default-filename in QFileDialog-call) or do you automatically want to save to the textfile (just remove QFileDialog and save to text.txt)?

Comment: I want to automatically select the text file (and then automatically save it using the QFileDialog)

Comment: Did you try to find the button on the dialog and call "click" function, or just simply send "Enter" key event to the dialog?

Comment: I only tried to click enter, that didn't work. But from what I've heard the button is part of the QFileDialog, so theres no way to find him.

Comment: @RandomDisplayName, I think, there is no file with name "/tmp/test.txt" in the dialog. Did you try to set the directory first with `fd->setDirectory("/tmp")`, and than select the file `fd->selectFile("test.txt");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectFile method does not work if the filedialog is visible and if the focus is set to the line edit widget. From the qfiledialog.cpp (QT 5.2):

```
if (!isVisible() || !d->lineEdit()->hasFocus())
    d->lineEdit()->setText(file);
```

For our automated tests, we just hide the filedialog for a moment, call selectFile() and show it again

Comment: Thanks! This had me completely stumped!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QWidgetList topWidgets = QApplication::topLevelWidgets();
foreach (QWidget *w, topWidgets) {
    if (QFileDialog *fd = qobject_cast<QFileDialog *>(w)) {
        fd->hide();
        fd->selectFile("/tmp/test.txt");
        fd->show();
        fd->exec();
    }
}
```